# Como pegar conteúdo de uma div com a mesma classe?

Tags: jquery

Acho que o titulo está bem autoexplicativo mas vamos lá, eu tenho um retorno de um json que vem de um sql, que pode me dar a seguinte situação

```html
    <div class="conteudo-select" style="display: block;">
        <div class="razaoSocial">
           <a onclick="pegarValor(); return false;">Nicolas e Yuri Contábil ME</a>
        </div> 
        <div class="nomeFantasia">
            <a onclick="pegarValor(); return false;">ny contabilidade</a>
        </div> 
        <div class="razaoSocial">
            <a onclick="pegarValor(); return false;">Jennifer e Thiago Lavanderia Ltda</a>
        </div> 
        <div class="nomeFantasia">
            <a onclick="pegarValor(); return false;">jt lavanderia</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Eu estou precisando pegar o conteúdo dentro da tag a...

tentei com o dado =  `event.srcElement.innerText;` porém não funciona no Firefox, nem colocando parâmetro na função  `function pegarValor(event) {`

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso que eu preciso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isto :

HTML :

```
   <div class="conteudo-select" style="display: block;">
    <div class="razaoSocial">
       <a onclick="getValor(this.text);" href="#">Nicolas e Yuri Contábil ME</a>
    </div> 
    <div class="nomeFantasia">
        <a onclick="getValor(this.text);" href="#">ny contabilidade</a>
    </div> 
    <div class="razaoSocial">
        <a onclick="getValor(this.text);" href="#">Jennifer e Thiago Lavanderia Ltda</a>
    </div> 
    <div class="nomeFantasia">
        <a onclick="getValor(this.text);" href="#">jt lavanderia</a>
    </div>
```

Javascript :

```
function getValor(aa){
  console.info(aa);
}
```

Comment: valeu pela resposta, acredito que funcionaria perfeitamente tb

Answer (score 1):

Sem modificar a sua estrutura original, podes fazer passando `this` para as funções;

```js
function pegarValor(el){
  console.log(el.innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo-select" style="display: block;">
  <div class="razaoSocial">
    <a onclick="pegarValor(this); return false;">Nicolas e Yuri Contábil ME</a>
  </div> 
  <div class="nomeFantasia">
    <a onclick="pegarValor(this); return false;">ny contabilidade</a>
  </div> 
  <div class="razaoSocial">
    <a onclick="pegarValor(this); return false;">Jennifer e Thiago Lavanderia Ltda</a>
  </div> 
  <div class="nomeFantasia">
    <a onclick="pegarValor(this); return false;">jt lavanderia</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: valeu, funcionou perfeitamente